# Image not aligning horizontally after trying several common solutions

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, centering

It works fine on Desktop because I use width: 100%.  But on Mobile I do width: 50% and try to center it.

I have tried setting the img.youtube-thumb to margin-left: auto; and margin-right: auto;  I've also tried setting the images parent element to text-align: center; and having the image displayed as inline-block, and that doesn't work either.

I'm not sure what else to try, as it seems that every S.O answer I run into provides one of the two above solutions.

Here's a CodePen but I'm not sure how valuable it'll be since I cant seem to get it exact without pasting the entire project into the pen. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOEQKg

Here's the HTML for one of the images:

```
<section class="container-fluid">
<div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_6_of_12">
        <div class="thumbnail project">
            <h3>Some title</h3>
            <div class="youtube-container">
              <div class="youtube-player" data-id="ZMJP-FFzaZk">
                <div>
                  <img class="youtube-thumb" src="//i.ytimg.com/vi/ZMJP-FFzaZk/hqdefault.jpg">
                  <div class="play-button"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="caption">
                <p>blablablablabla</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my CSS code:

```
/* inside media query */
.youtube-player {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

/* inside media query*/
  img.youtube-thumb {
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }

.project {
  text-align: center;
}


/* for entire site */
.youtube-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 300px; /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}

/* for entire site */
div {
  text-align: left;
}


/* 12 Grid Column Setup??? */
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Does your positioning need to be absolute? To get `margin: 0 auto` to work in your case, you can use relative positioning. Forked your Codepen to show you: http://codepen.io/abhisharma2/pen/XdYyBz

Comment: No, abhi, It doesn't need to be absolute.  When I apply your code to the actual site, the image disappears of the site. I hate testing mobile. It's always different on the testing tools compared to the actual site.

Comment: Crap, yeah I hear ya. If you develop on Chrome, you can try toggling to mobile view [https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/?hl=en]. Or if you can somehow share the full source I can take a look and see what else might be causing your issue.

Comment: abhi, I've had troubles with Chrome. I've used the mobile view before, and it  came out different then the actual result on my real phone, although I only tried it once and had some Wonky JS going on at the time,  I figured it out by the way. The ordering of my CSS was bad. I had a style underneath my media query that altered the positioning back to absolute, and that was my problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: awesome! glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
img.youtube-thumb {
bottom: 0;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
max-width: 50%;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
```

}

into this:

```
img.youtube-thumb {
top: 0;
display:block;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:auto;
max-width: 50%;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
```

}

Hope it helps